# accessing elements of a child window via javascript in a parent window across domain AND protocol

Tags: javascript

I'm building an automation tool at work, and I've hit a bit of a snag... The task is to automate the laborious process of navigating a large web-based GUI which sends queries to a database based on the values entered in various fields.  We do not have access to the database itself or the server on which the web-GUI is located.  Furthermore, the protocol for the web-GUI is https.  Is there any way to have javascript open the web-GUI in a new window and then act on it [clicking buttons, reading returned text strings etc.]?  The implementation doesn't have to be javascript (autoIT would do the same job much more easily) but I am curious as to how the access denied errors might be overcome.  I have read about certain workarounds, but none of them went so far as to actually attempt to interact with elements of the cross-domain document.  I have also discovered easyXDM, but it doesn't solve the protocol discrepancy, and I'm not certain it would work for my situation anyway.  Any input would be appreciated!
thanks,
CCJ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not going to be able to do cross domain because of the [same origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript).

Sounds like you should do something with [greasemonkey](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greasemonkey) or with [selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) to automate it.